# Enable/disable textfield when a certain button is clicked on

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, playframework, textfield

I have a disabled textfield and it is also readOnly and I am trying to get it where you click on a certain button and it makes the textfield enabled and not readOnly so the user can edit it.

This is what I have for my code so far:

```
buttonid.on({'click': function (){
        if(Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').getForm().isDirty()){
            Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').setDisabled(false);
        }
        else{
            Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').setDisabled(true);
        }
    }});
```

This code is not working and I know there is a better way to do this.

Comment: you should remove the `disabled` and/or `readonly` attribute from the text element http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Comment: I would do that, but I want it to be disabled and readOnly and then when they click the button, it becomes where they can edit the textfield.

Comment: Yeah, leave them in at first, but in the callback that is executed when they click the button, you should programmatically remove the `disabled` and/or `readonly` attributes as per @JustinRusso's answer

Comment: can you provide the config for the textfield showing its disabled? Also when you say not working, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
buttonid.on({'click': function (){
        var yourTextField = Ext.getCmp('textfieldid');
        if(yourTextField.getForm().isDirty()){
            yourTextField.enable();
            yourTextField.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        else{
            yourTextField.disable();
            yourTextField.setReadOnly(true);
        }
    }});
```

[Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) you will find all textfield methods.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the above code and then tinker it a bit. I ended up just doing this since I have the textfield disabled and set readOnly to true in my xtype: 'textfield'...bUpdateSwitch.on({'click': function (){
            var yourtextfield = Ext.getCmp('textfieldid');
             yourtextfield .enable();
             yourtextfield .setReadOnly(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
buttonid.on('click', function (){
    var textF = Ext.getCmp('textfieldid');
    if(Ext.getCmp('textfieldid').isDirty()) {
        textF.enable(); // enable textfield
        textF.setReadOnly(false); // can edit field
    }
    else{
        textF.disable();   // disable textfield
        textF.setReadOnly(true);   // read only is true, so can not edit
        // Any way, you do not need to set field readOnly if you disable it, cause user will not be able to modify it.
    }
});
```

Here are references to methods used in above code :

[textfield.enable()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-enable) - enables the textfield

[textfield.disable()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-disable) - disables the textfield

[textfield.setReadOnly(readOnly)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setReadOnly) - whether to set textfield readOnly or not, pass true/false

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. But I am getting the same issue that I was before. When I click on my button, it remains disabled. This is the code that I have in my textfield not sure if this helps at all. {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Text Field',
                            id: 'textfield',
                            readOnly: true,
                            disabled: true,
                            width: 65
                        }

Comment: Could the readOnly and disable methods be overridden by the properties inside the textfield? I tried to take them out, but seems to not have much of an effect